# Open window of an application and move it to a different Space in OSX, is it possible?

Tags: bash, macos, applescript

for some application I would like to have an "instance" of it running in Space (Apple's workspace) 4 and another one in number 2. How can I somehow tell (in bash/applescript or whatever) to an instance of an application, to "move" to Space number N? Applescript? Bash? External app?

I want to do this automatic and for a lot of different apps. So using the mouse or assigning applications in preferences does not work for me.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: What is an "instance" of an application? Only one instance per application is normally running in OS X. Are you talking about different windows?

Comment: yes, or better, different processes. for instance, i open the terminal and type Firefox &, and later the same Firefox &, so I have two different processes of the same application

Comment: By the way, can you show what your "Firefox" command translates to?  If I try to launch two instances of Firefox by `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin &`, Firefox puts up an error window "A copy of Firefox is already open.  Only one copy of Firefox can be open at a time."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't unless you make more than one copy of the application and change its bundle identifier (not recommended for lots of reasons).  Spaces works on an application basis, not a per-instance basis (which is uncommon on OS X for GUI apps anyway) nor on a per-window basis of an app.

Comment: Ned, thanks a lot for your valuable help but i am giving up. Unfortunately this tasks seems impossible. In Linux it would be o problem, as the way of how to do this is for sure well documented and open source. thanks

Comment: the question for me is: for a given progem, i.e. safari, how to open, programatically two windows in different spaces

Comment: I think people understand your question.  The answer remains: you can't, using Spaces scripting interface; you have to move the window after it is created. Spaces was something that was added to OS X in a fairly recent release (10.5) and, unfortunately, wasn't designed to accommodate this.  To make it really work might require application changes as well. Sorry!

Comment: Hi Ned, I found a workaround for my general problem. It's so basic ...

I an script I store all apps taht I need to open with their respective documents or input files. WHen it is prepared, I just go to the space number that I want, and I run it there. Voilà. So obius

thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

To move an already open window into another space click and hold on the window's title bar and then do ctrl-NUM_KEY_OF_SPACE.  So, to move a window to space #2 use  click+hold the title bar and press ctrl+2.  Too bad this shortcut (even with other modifier keys) doesn't work on the window currently in focus.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is achievable by simply running the executable directly.
For example, the following example code will open 3 different instances of Safari.

Each can then by placed in different Spaces, and CMD+Tab will correctly shift between them.
Copy and paste this in a Terminal window (paste all 3 lines at once):

```
nohup /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari &
nohup /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari &
nohup /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari &
```

The trailing ampersand has the application run in the background, and the leading nohup makes it possible to quit Terminal.app without it closing the opened applications. You could easily be put into a script or AppleScript app, and place it in your dock.

Comment: yes you are right. but what i need is something like; open Firefox in Space number 2 . Everything done scriptically, without user interactions. That is the point